# По поводу кавычек

Tags: лингвистика

А кавычки являются знаком препинания? То есть, вопросы относительно кавычек можно считать вопросами из области пунктуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки — парный знак препинания в виде лапок (" ") или елочек (« »), который употребляется для выделения прямой речи, цитат, отсылок, названий литературных произведений, газет, журналов, предприятий, а также отдельных слов, если они включаются в текст не в своём обычном значении, используются в ироническом смысле, предлагаются впервые или, наоборот, как устаревшие, и т.п.  Раз это знак препинания, то да, вопросы постановки кавычек можно отнести к пунктуационным.